# DisplayFormat DataFormatString not working with EditorFor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am new to MVC, and am trying to format phone numbers in both display and edit mode.  I am using the following data annotations on phone number:

```
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Work Phone")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
```

In the view, I have:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

According to my understanding, this should work, but the phone number is not formatted in either display or edit mode.  I have also tried the following in the view:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhone, "{0:###-###-####}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

but this doesn't work either.  What am I missing?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: A `DataFormatString` on a `string` property does not make sense.

Comment: Oh.  I was afraid of that.  Thanks.

Comment: I changed the phone numbers to data type long.  Now the phone number displays correctly in display mode using DisplayFor, but in edit mode using EditorFor (as above) the phone number doesn't display at all!

Comment: Displays the value fine using your first example-  `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhone)` - but it won't for the 2nd - that syntax is for `TextBoxFor()` - i.e. `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WorkPhone, "{0:###-###-####}")`. But because the property is `long` it will never bind to your model when you submit because the value contains `-` characters. You should look at using a jquery mask control.

Comment: It doesn't display using the first example either.  It doesn't display the number at all.

Comment: Works fine for me. If I set the set the value of `WorkPhone` to `1112223333` it displays a textbox with `111-222-3333` (but as I noted, its a bit pointless since it wont bind, and it also would not work correctly with leading zeros)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139436/discussion-between-dwight-mendoza-and-stephen-muecke).